# Index of a maximum element in TensorFlow tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensorflow

How can I get index of a maximum element of a tensor along a selected axis in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sorry, already figured that out. It is:

```
tf.argmax(input, axis, name=None)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argmax